# SQL and Oracle query to extract every thing before last two periods

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to extract every thing before last two periods

eg.

Input: `AA.BBB.12.11.cc`

Output: `AA.BBB.12`

Following is the sample query I am using but that returns only the characters before  first  period, but that is not I needed.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column,'[^.]+',1,1)
 AS output
 FROM MY_Table  t where t.column is not null and rownum=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(t.column, '\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$', '')
FROM MY_table
WHERE t.column IS NOT NULL AND rownum = 1;
```

The regex pattern `\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$` will match starting with the second to last dot, all content until the end (including also the last dot).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as I was wondering about the symbols.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` as following:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      SUBSTR('AA.BBB.12.11.ccCC', 1, INSTR('AA.BBB.12.11.ccCC', '.', -2, 2) - 1) AS RESULT
  3  FROM DUAL;

RESULT
---------
AA.BBB.12

SQL>
```

**-- Update --**

For the question asked in the comment, use the following query:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      SUBSTR('AA.BB.CC.DD', 1, INSTR('AA.BB.CC.DD', '.', 1, 3) - 1) AS RESULT
  3  FROM DUAL;

RESULT
--------
AA.BB.CC

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This is also working. Unfortunately I have only one choice to mark the answer.

Comment: Yes, I can understand. But glad that we (SO) are able to help you growing.. Keep coding Keep learning!! Cheers!!

Comment: Suppose I have an input string AA.BB.cc.dd and need AA.BB.cc as output what alteration I need to do in the above query (Neglect every thing after first 3 periods rather than extracting everything before last two periods) ?

Comment: See the **Update** section in the answer.